# Javascript using round to the nearest 10

Tags: javascript

I would like to round integers using JavaScript. For example:

```
10 = 10
11 = 20
19 = 20
24 = 30
25 = 30
29 = 30
```

Comment: How does `10` possibly round up to `20`? 15, yes; 14 and below would round to `10`.

Comment: Also, what exactly did you try?

Comment: I suggest you rephrase your question to "How do I round an integer up to the nearest 10?"

Comment: I think you want the Math.ceil() function, but as David said, I'm not sure how 10 could round to 20. However, 11 could with the aforementioned function.

Comment: Looks like your rounding to the nearest 10 but why would 10 round to 20?

Comment: @DavidThomas Fixed

Answer (score 210):

This should do it:

```
Math.ceil(N / 10) * 10;
```

Where N is one of your numbers.

Comment: In that case he could do `Math.ceil((N+1) / 10) * 10;`

Comment: Math.ceil returns ["The smallest integer greater than or equal to the given number."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil)  
So it works for all cases (`Math.ceil(10 / 10) * 10 = 10`)

Comment: Alternatively could have also be done by a simple Math: var result = (remainder = N%10) ? N+(10-remainder) : N; (where N is a given number, remainder is a temp variable initialize to 0).

Comment: @SridharKritha while that math is simple enough, I would have to read that and spend time figuring out why the guy before me chose to write it that way instead of using Math.ceil. And "the guy before me" could very well be me ;)

Answer (score 32):

To round a number to the next greatest multiple of 10, add one to the number before 
getting the Math.ceil of a division by 10. Multiply the result by ten.

**Math.ceil((n+1)/10)*10;**

```
1->10
2->10
3->10
4->10
5->10
6->10
7->10
8->10
9->10
10->20
11->20
12->20
13->20
14->20
15->20
16->20
17->20
18->20
19->20
20->30
21->30
22->30
23->30
24->30
25->30
26->30
27->30
28->30
29->30
30->40
35-> 40
40-> 50
45-> 50
50-> 60
55-> 60
60-> 70
65-> 70
70-> 80
75-> 80
80-> 90
85-> 90
90-> 100
95-> 100
100-> 110
```

Comment: How can you make this work with negative values? nearest(330, -5) should be 225, this return 330 :/

Comment: It 'rounds' to the next greatest multiple of 10, 220-229 all are=230.

Comment: This rounds 10 to 20, so is not applicable for the case 10 = 10

Answer (score 17):

`Math.round()` rounds to the nearest integer. To round to any other digit, divide and multiply by powers of ten.

One such method is this:

```
function round(num,pre) {
    if( !pre) pre = 0;
    var pow = Math.pow(10,pre);
    return Math.round(num*pow)/pow;
}
```

You can make similar functions for `floor` and `ceiling`. However, no matter what you do, `10` will never round to `20`.

Comment: What does `pre` stand for in this example?

Comment: It's `pre`cision.

Comment: I gotta say, this is a really slick answer.

Answer (score 7):

or this

```
var i = 20;
var yourNumber = (parseInt(i/10, 10)+1)*10;
```

Comment: This rounds 20 to 30, so is not applicable for the case `10 = 10`