# Generate random integer rounded to nearest whole number

Tags: javascript, html, math, rounding

I am wondering how to generate a random integer that gets rounded to nearest whole number,
e.g. random number: 436, == 440, or 521, == 520. basically just rounding the random number to the nearest whole number. (JavaScript)

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min; //gets random number
//then I want to round the number here, maybe even in the same line as where the number is 
//being generated.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11022488/javascript-using-round-to-the-nearest-10/11022517

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript using round to the nearest 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11022488/javascript-using-round-to-the-nearest-10)

Comment: Just generate random integer in **smaller range** and multiply by 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sould get the job done

```
 Math.round((Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min) / 10) * 10
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do the job:

```
result = Math.round((Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min) / 10) * 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

To round a number, you can use `Math.floor(n / 10) * 10`. Example:

```js
function randomRoundNumber(min, max) {
  return Math.round((Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min) / 10) * 10;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="console.log(randomRoundNumber(parseInt(prompt('min?')),parseInt(prompt('max?'))))">Random number</button>
```